# Redirect non WWW urls to WWW urls through htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I am using apache 2.2 on  a windows OS , 
I need to redirect non www urls to www urls , i checked online , and found this seems to be working for many

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.co\.uk [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But if i use the same rewrite rules i get www urls with a dot in the end :

ex :

```
http://example.com/test redirects to
http://www.example.com.
$1 is "." and its failing to add all params
```

Comment: Can you put the real thing you wrote in .htaccess?

Comment: @Aseman RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite\.local [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.local/$1 [R=301,L]

Answer (score 1):

Ok!
you put this on you `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite\.local [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ mysite.local/$1 [R=301,L]
```

it means if host equals to mysite.local (end of host not mentioned!) so every url redirects to directory `mysite.local`!
You should use this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mysite\.local
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mysite.local/$1 [L,R=301]
```

So every URL that host IS NOT equal to www.mysite.local will redirect to this one! but remember if you want to create subdomain, PUT DOCUMENT ROOT OF THIS SUBDOMAIN OUT OF WWW.MYSITE.LOCAL DOCUMENT ROOT! (it's better!)

Comment: it still redirects to www.mysite.local. with the params dropped

Comment: @Deepak it's easy code that used every where! can you give me entire .htaccess file?(if you can please upload it to somewhere I can download it)